# Number of solutions number theory problem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations, integer-partitions

I am wondering how many nonnegative solutions the following Diophantine equation has: $$x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_n=r$$ if $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq \dots \leq x_n$

I know if a sequence can be non-decreasing answer is $ {n+r-1}\choose{r} $

Can I use this fact to solve the problem?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, you could take $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ and divide by the number of permutations, i.e. $n!$. But you have to work out the details.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. It has problem when some elements are equal. also $ \binom{n+r-1}{r} $ is not always divisible on n!.

Comment: You are correct. I don't think that you can solve it that simple. The solution is quite complicated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)

Comment: The OP problem reduces to partition function only when $n \ge r$, otherwise some solutions must be discarded, in any case I believe there is no known formula.

Comment: Hy to clarify the question it seems $n$ is fixed, if so it could be calculated in a way...

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the number of integer partitions with up to $n$ parts whose sum is $r$.  (If $r < n$, then some of the $x_i$ must be 0.)  The triangle of values is given in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences as [A026820](https://oeis.org/A026820) (which uses $n$ for your $r$ and $k$ for your $n$).  If you express this as a sum of partition counts with exactly $k$ parts [A008284](https://oeis.org/A008284), you can generate an expression in terms of $p(n)$, the number of partitions of $n$, although this has no simple closed form.

The binomial coefficient $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ would be relevant without the restriction that $x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n$.  In that case you would be dealing with integer compositions, which are often easier to analyze than partitions.